# Minimagick resize image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy intentando realizar un crop con minimagick en Rails y se está produciendo un error algo extraño.

El código es el siguiente:

```
def resize_crop
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.resize model.width
    end
    # resize_to_fill model.width, 0
  end
```

La primera vez que llamo a la función que redimensiona la imagen me devuelve el siguiente error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Crop Failed to
>   manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error:
>   `identify /tmp/mini_magick20170111-8437-12evsch.jpeg` failed with
>   error: identify.im6: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x23 0

En cambio la siguiente vez se ejecuta correctamente.
He probado a desactivar la validación de minimagick, pero veo que el problema viene de mogrify.

¿Alguna sugerencia para solucionar este comportamiento?

Answer (score 0):

No pensaste en generar un thumb mejor ? si te decides a redimensionar de esa manera te recomiendo ir al controlador de photouploader  app/uploaders/photouploaders dentro de ese lugar hay un lugar comentado:
  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  aqui saca #-version :thumb do
     aqui saca #-process resize_to_fill: [100, 100]
   aqui saca # -end 
de esa forma en donde estan los parametros puedes decidir en cuanto dejar el resize, luego cuando hagas el el image tag <%= image_tag(parametro.img.thumb) %>  llamas al resize agrega el .thumb y tendras tu imagen en formato arreglado

Comment: las gemas que utilice para eso fueron carriewave, apt image magic, gem mini magic